# Revisited question Lebesgue Measure of Symmetric Difference is 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Following this question:[Dudley Section 3.4, Problem 1: Lebesgue Measure of Symmetric Difference is 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302846/dudley-section-3-4-problem-1-lebesgue-measure-of-symmetric-difference-is-0?rq=1)

> Let E be a Lebesgue measurable set, such that for all $x$ in a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $m(E\Delta (E+x)) =0$. Show that either $m (E)$ or $m(\mathbb{R}/E) =0$.

I did not understand the first answer in this question. Can anyone add some details for that answer? Or another approach..

---

Proof: I try to use the contradiction by following two results from [For a set of positive measure there is an interval in which its density is high, $\mu(E\cap I)> \rho \mu(I)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103306/for-a-set-of-positive-measure-there-is-an-interval-in-which-its-density-is-high):

> Let $E$ be Lebesgue measurable, with $\mu(E)>0$ (here $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure). Then:
>
> 1. for any $0<\rho<1$, there exists an open interval $I$ such that $\mu(E \cap I)> \rho \cdot \mu(I)$.
> 2. the set $E-E = \{x-y : x, y \in E\}$ contains an (open) interval centered at $0$ (in particular, if $\rho > 3/4$, the text I am using suggests that $(-\frac{1}{2} \mu(I), \frac{1}{2}\mu(I)) \subseteq E-E$).

Now, suppose that $m(E)>0$ and $m(E^c)>0$. Then for $\rho=\frac{3}{4}$ so that there is $I_1$ with
$$
\mu(E\cap I_1)>\frac{3}{4}\mu(I_1)
$$
and apply the result to $E^c$ to get there is a interval $I_2$ so that
$$
\mu(E\cap I_2)<\frac{1}{4}\mu(I_2)
$$

Then by the second result, we have there is an open interval so that
$$
(-0.5m(I_1), 0.5m(I_2))\subset E-E
$$
and
$$
(-0.5m(I_2), 0.5m(I_2))\subset E^c-E^c.
$$

Since $m(E\Delta (E+q))=0$ (i.e., $E=E^c$ a.e.), then for $E\cap (I_1\cup I_2)$ we have
$$
E\cap (I_1\cup I_2)=(E+q)\cap (I_1\cup I_2) a.e.
$$

Thus, $m(E\cap (I_1\cup I_2))=m((E+q)\cap (I_1\cup I_2))$

Then for $x\in (-0.5m(I_1), 0.5m(I_2))$, we have $x=a-b$ for some $a, b\in E$, and for $y\in (-0.5m(I_2), 0.5m(I_2))$, we have $y=c-d$ for some $c,d \in E^c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a restatement of @mathworker21 's answer, slightly simplified and clarified. I'm posting this per the OP's request as the OP remains confused about that answer.

As the OP already mentioned, if $\mu(E) > 0$ and $\mu(E^c) > 0$, then there is a finite open interval $I_1$ with $\mu(E \cap I_1) > \frac{3}{4}\mu(I_1)$ and a finite open interval $I_2$ with $\mu(E \cap I_2) < \frac{1}{4}\mu(I_2)$. Let $x_i$ be the center point of $I_i$ and $r_i$ be the radius of $I_i$, i.e., $I_i = (x_i - r_i, x_i + r_i)$ for $i = 1, 2$. The first point I'll observe here is that, by replacing $I_1$ or $I_2$ if necessary, I may assume $r_1$ and $r_2$ are close to each other. More precisely, I may assume $r_2 \leq r_1 < 3r_2$.

Indeed, if we have started with $r_1 < r_2$, then we may divide $I_2$ into finitely many intervals $\{J_k\}_{k = 1}^n$ with $J_k$ having radius $\frac{1}{2}r_1$ for all $k < n$ and $J_n$ having radius between $\frac{1}{2}r_1$ and $r_1$. (Just divide $I_2$ into equal intervals of radius $\frac{1}{2}r_1$. Then the remainder has radius smaller than $\frac{1}{2}r_1$. Add the remainder to the final interval to get an interval of radius between $\frac{1}{2}r_1$ and $r_1$.) Now, if all $J_k$ satisfies $\mu(E \cap J_k) \geq \frac{1}{4}\mu(J_k)$, then summing over all $k$ yields $\mu(E \cap I_2) \geq \frac{1}{4}\mu(I_2)$, contradicting the assumption on $I_2$. Hence, we may replace $I_2$ by a $J_k$ with $\mu(E \cap J_k) < \frac{1}{4}\mu(J_k)$. As $J_k$ has radius between $\frac{1}{2}r_1$ and $r_1$, we now have $\frac{1}{2}r_1 \leq r_2 \leq r_1$, i.e., $r_2 \leq r_1 \leq 2r_2 < 3r_2$.

Similarly, if we have started with $r_1 \geq 3r_2$, then we may divide $I_1$ into finitely many intervals $\{J_k\}_{k = 1}^n$ with $J_k$ having radius $r_2$ for all $k < n$ and $J_n$ having radius between $r_2$ and $2r_2$. By a similar argument, we may replace $I_1$ by one of the $J_k$. Then $r_2 \leq r_1 \leq 2r_2 < 3r_2$.

To summarize, there exists $I_i = (x_i - r_i, x_i + r_i)$ s.t. $\mu(E \cap I_1) > \frac{3}{4}\mu(I_1)$, $\mu(E \cap I_2) < \frac{1}{4}\mu(I_2)$, and $r_2 \leq r_1 < 3r_2$. Let $r = \frac{3r_2 - r_1}{4}$. Since $r_1 < 3r_2$, we have $r > 0$. Then the interval $(x_1 - x_2 - r, x_1 - x_2 + r)$ is open and nonempty, so there is $z \in (x_1 - x_2 - r, x_1 - x_2 + r)$ s.t. $\mu(E\,\Delta\,(E + z)) = 0$. Note that,

$$\begin{split}
E\,\Delta\,(E + z) &\supseteq (E \cap I_1) \setminus (E + z)\\
&= (E \cap I_1) \setminus [(E + z) \cap I_1]\\
&= (E \cap I_1) \setminus ([E \cap (I_1 - z)] + z)\\
&= (E \cap I_1) \setminus ([E \cap (x_1 - z - r_1, x_1 - z + r_1)] + z)
\end{split}$$

Let $s = \frac{3}{4}r_1 - \frac{1}{4}r_2 > 0$. Observe that, as $z \in (x_1 - x_2 - r, x_1 - x_2 + r)$, we have,

$$\begin{split}
x_1 - z - r_1 \geq x_2 - r - r_1 = x_2 - \frac{3}{4}r_2 + \frac{1}{4}r_1 - r_1 = x_2 - \frac{3}{4}r_2 - \frac{3}{4}r_1 = x_2 - r_2 - s\\
x_1 - z + r_1 \leq x_2 + r + r_1 = x_2 + \frac{3}{4}r_2 - \frac{1}{4}r_1 + r_1 = x_2 + \frac{3}{4}r_2 + \frac{3}{4}r_1 = x_2 + r_2 + s
\end{split}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{split}
(x_1 - z - r_1, x_1 - z + r_1) &\subseteq (x_2 - r_2 - s, x_2 + r_2 + s)\\
&= I_2 \cup (x_2 - r_2 - s, x_2 - r_2] \cup [x_2 + r_2, x_2 + r_2 + s)
\end{split}$$

So,

$$\begin{split}
\mu([E \cap (x_1 - z - r_1, x_1 - z + r_1)] + z) &= \mu(E \cap (x_1 - z - r_1, x_1 - z + r_1))\\
&\leq \mu(E \cap I_2) + \mu((x_2 - r_2 - s, x_2 - r_2]) + \mu([x_2 + r_2, x_2 + r_2 + s))\\
&< \frac{1}{4}\mu(I_2) + 2s\\
&= \frac{1}{2}r_2 + \frac{3}{2}r_1 - \frac{1}{2}r_2\\
&= \frac{3}{2}r_1
\end{split}$$

So,

$$\begin{split}
\mu(E\,\Delta\,(E + z)) &\geq \mu((E \cap I_1) \setminus ([E \cap (x_1 - z - r_1, x_1 - z + r_1)] + z))\\
&\geq \mu(E \cap I_1) - \mu([E \cap (x_1 - z - r_1, x_1 - z + r_1)] + z)\\
&> \frac{3}{4}\mu(I_1) - \frac{3}{2}r_1\\
&= 0
\end{split}$$

This contradicts $\mu(E\,\Delta\,(E + z)) = 0$. So our original assumption must be wrong, i.e., we must have $\mu(E) = 0$ or $\mu(E^c) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to use the second result"the set $E-E = \{x-y : x, y \in E\}$ contains an (open) interval centered at $0$ (in particular, if $\rho > 3/4$, the text I am using suggests that $(-\frac{1}{2} \mu(I), \frac{1}{2}\mu(I)) \subseteq E-E$)" to simplify the proof?

Comment: @Hermi Maybe, I’m not sure. To me, though, what you need is more akin to $E^c - E$ containing an interval rather than $E - E$ containing an interval.

Comment: Ok, I just proved that $E-E^c$ contained an interval. If this is true, can we simplify the proof?

Comment: One question about your "assume that $r_2\le r_1<3r_2$. Since your divide $I_2$ with $n-1$ copies of some intervals with length $r_1$. Then $2r_2=|I_2|=(n-1)|I_1|+r$ with $0\le r<|I_1|=2r_1$. So why do we have the final interval is length between $r_1$ and $2r_2$?

Comment: @Hermi I'm not sure what you are talking about? There are three cases: If we already have $r_2 \leq r_1 < 3r_2$, there's nothing more to do. If $r_1 < r_2$, I dealt with that in the third paragraph by dividing $I_2$ into intervals of radius between $\frac{1}{2}r_1$ and $r_1$. If $r_1 \geq 3r_2$, I dealt with that in the fourth paragraph by dividing $I_1$ into intervals of radius between $r_2$ and $2r_2$. I never divided $I_2$ into intervals with radius $r_1$? Which case are you confused about?

Comment: @Hermi As for your other question, it was my bad, I should have been clearer. When I said "what you need is more akin to $E^c - E$ containing an interval", I did not mean to imply that using $E^c - E$ containing an interval would simplify the proof. I simply meant to say that, because the result is more similar in spirits to $E^c - E$ containing an interval, I highly doubt using the fact that $E - E$ contains an interval would help, that's all. By saying they are similar in spirits, I meant the following:

Comment: @Hermi $E^c - E$ containing an interval is the same as saying there is an interval $I$ s.t. whenever $z \in I$, $(E + z) \cap E^c$ is nonempty. While what I proved is the same as saying there is an interval $I$ s.t. whenever $z \in I$, $(E + z) \cap E^c = (E + z) \setminus E = [E \setminus (E - z)] + z$ has positive measure. This is strictly stronger than just saying $E^c - E$ contains an interval. Given that, what I meant is that I can't see how $E - E$ containing an interval would help.

Comment: @Hermi Though $E^c - E$ containing an interval probably won't help either. After all, $E^c - E$ can contain an interval even if $E$ or $E^c$ is null (just let $E$ to be a singleton or $E^c$ to be a singleton). I, personally, don't see a way to simplify the proof much without using some more powerful machinery.

Comment: @Hermi Oh, I think I figured out what you meant in your second question. As written in the answer, I'm "[adding] the remainder to the final interval". So, if you are dividing $I_2$ into intervals of length $r_1$, then the remainder has length between $0$ and $r_1$. But I'm not using the remainder itself, but I'm adding it to the previous interval of length $r_1$. That gives me something of length between $r_1$ and $2r_1$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh! I see. Yes. It makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Assume both $m(E)$ and $m(\mathbb{R}\setminus E) =: m(E^c)$ are nonzero. Then each of $E$ and $E^c$ have positive Lebesgue measure. So there are points $x \in E$ and $y \in E^c$ for which $$\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{2r}m\bigl(E \cap (x-r,x+r)\bigr) = 1$$ and $$\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{2r}m\bigl(E^c \cap (y-r,y+r)\bigr) = 1.$$ Indeed, $m$-a.e. point of $E$ would work for $x$ and $m$-a.e. point of $E^c$ would work for $y$.

Note that the second equation is equivalent to $$\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{2r}m\bigl(E \cap (y-r,y+r)\bigr) = 0.$$ Now, take $r > 0$ small enough so that $$m\bigl(E \cap (x-r,x+r)\bigr) > \frac{3}{4}(2r)$$ and $$m\bigl(E \cap (y-r,y+r)\bigr) < \frac{1}{4}(2r).$$ By assumption, there is some $z \in (y-x-\frac{r}{10},y-x+\frac{r}{10})$ with $m\bigl(E \Delta (E+z)\bigr) = 0$. I'll let you finish the contradiction from here.

Comment: Hi, I came across your answer, can you help me understand why there are $x \in E$ and $y \in E^c$ such that your first two equations hold? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @JeffreyJao The following is a standard theorem in measure theory. Let $E$ be a set of positive measure. Then almost every $x \in E$ is a "Lebesgue point of $E$", which means that $x$ satisfies $$\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{2r}m\bigl(E \cap (x-r,x+r)\bigr) = 1.$$

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you! But can we just use this result https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103306/for-a-set-of-positive-measure-there-is-an-interval-in-which-its-density-is-high directly? I mean that for any $\rho>0$, there is an interval $I$ so that $\mu(E\cap I)>\rho \mu(I)$? If using this result, how to get your second inequality that $\mu(E\cap (y-r, y+r))<\frac{1}{4} (2r)$? Thank you!

Comment: @Hermi Apply it to $E^c$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I am still confused. Because I try to avoid using the density theorem that you wrote in the beginning. I have updated my process in question that I understand that we can do that there exists two intervals $I_1, I_2$ so that $m(E\cap I_1)>\frac{3}{4}m(I_1)$ and $m(E\cap I_2)<\frac{1}{4}m(I_2)$. But how to get our contradiction... I think that we it is nontrivial to assume that $I_1=(x-r,x+r)$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Well, if you take a look at the question I linked, the answer given there covers part of what you have provided. My question is about the latter part: why can we assume that the two intervals have the same length, and why does this assumption contradict our conditions? Could you provide a detailed answer, please? Thank you!