# Showing that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n dx = \int_{0}^{1}f dx$ where $(f_n)$ are sequence of continuous functions converging to $f$ pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my proof for the below false statement:

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions that converge pointwise to some Riemann-integrable function $f$. Then, for any $x\in[0,1]$,
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx=\int_0^1 f(x) dx$$

My attempt at proof:

Let $x\in[0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$. Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. for any $n>N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Then,

\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx - \int_0^1 f(x)dx\right| &= \left|\int_0^1 [f_n(x) - f(x)]dx\right| \\
&\le \int_0^1 |f_n(x) - f(x)|dx \\
&\le \epsilon \cdot (1-0)=\epsilon
\end{align}

I think all my steps are correct. Did I overlook something here?

Comment: $N$ depends on $x$.

Comment: @AnneBauval When integrating, x changes?

Comment: Of course! $x$ takes all the values of the interval of integration.

Comment: @AnneBauval I thought $N$ depends on $n$. The expression $f_{N(x)}(x)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, $N$ depends on $x$ (and of course on $\epsilon$): for every $x\in[0,1]$ and every $\epsilon>0$, there exist an $N$ such that etc.

Comment: And the expression $f_{N(x)}(x)$ does make sense but is of no use.

Comment: You might be thinking of the fact that continuity implies uniform continuity on a compact interval. It's not true that convergence implies uniform convergence even for a sequence of continuous functions on a compact interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The false bit is
"Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. for any $n>N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$".

What you wrote looks like pointwise convergence but you used it as if it were uniform convergence further down for lack of proper logical clarity.

Pointwise convergence is:

$$\forall x \exists N(x)\in\mathbb N /  \forall n>N(x) |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

But instead you used uniform convergence, which is

$$ \exists N \in\mathbb N  / \forall x  \forall n>N |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

Obviously you can integrate only the second case, otherwise, as a comment states, your N depending on $x$, you never can be sure that it will not tend to infinity somewhere in the interval.

And as you know, uniform convergence of a continuous function on a compact allows interchanging the order of the limit and the integral.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample:

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$,
where $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R,$ with
\begin{equation*}
f_n(t) = \left\{\,
\begin{array}{ccl}
0 & \quad \text{if}\quad  & t\in 
\Big[ 0,\frac{1}{3n}\Big), \\
\quad
9n^{2} t-3n & \quad \text{if}\quad  &
t\in  \Big[\frac{1}{3n},\frac{2}{3n}\Big), \\ 
\quad 9n-9n^2t & \quad \text{if}\quad  &
t\in \Big[\frac{2}{3n},\frac{3}{3n}\Big), \\ 0 
& \quad \text{if}\quad & t\in \Big[
\frac{3}{3n},1\Big].
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
Then
$f_n(t)$, converges pointwise to 0, for every $x\in [0,1]$.
However, for every $n \in \mathbb N$
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 f_n(t)\,dt = 1 
\qquad\text{while}\qquad 
\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt = 0.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Hi there, can you please take a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851938/revisited-question-lebesgue-measure-of-symmetric-difference-is-0? Thank you!